# Error while upgrading from Rails 3.1 to Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Upgrade steps were performed as mentioned in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html

Right now I'm on Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.1.x (using system ruby). I installed RVM with ruby 1.8.7 and added to rails 3.2 and then I get the following error:

```
[app]$ rails console
Faraday: you may want to install system_timer for reliable timeouts
$HOME/src/qbol/tapp/config/environment.rb:16:in `add': undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:55:in `add'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:61:in `info'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:86
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:80
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from $HOME/src/app/config/environment.rb:48
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
        from $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:40
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6
```

This is on my development box. Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT: Below is the environment.rb. The error is happening on the last line App::Application.initialize!

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

module ActiveSupport
  class BufferedLogger

    def self.current_user
      Thread.current[:user]
    end
    def self.current_user=(user)
      Thread.current[:user] = user
    end

    def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block)
      return if @level > severity
      message = (message || (block && block.call) || progname).to_s
      level = {
        0 => "DEBUG",
        1 => "INFO ",
        2 => "WARN ",
        3 => "ERROR",
        4 => "FATAL"
      }[severity] || "UNKNOWN"

      user=BufferedLogger.current_user
      if(!user.nil?)
        idstr = "uid:#{user.id}"
        if !user.current_app_user.nil?
          idstr.concat(", acid: #{user.current_app_user.account_id}")
        end
      else
        idstr=""
      end

      message = "[%s: %s #{idstr}] %s" %
        ["#{level} pid: #{$$}", Time.now.strftime("%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), message]

      message = "#{message}\n" unless message[-1] == ?\n
      buffer << message
      auto_flush
      message
    end
  end
end

# Initialize the rails application
App::Application.initialize!
```

Comment: You should post your `config/environment.rb` file.

Comment: Added the environment.rb file in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening inside `ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger#add` method call and you appear to be monkey-patching this class. The internals of `ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger` have likely changing between the versions of Rails you're using.

Try removing all of the `ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger` code from your environment.rb to work past this error and get your app running. Then, if you still need the monkeypatch (don't know why), you'd have to rewrite it on top of the newer version of the class.